# Is it more efficient to search a file tree using hashing?

Tags: java, search, hashmap

So I am trying to optimize some code that I am working with. The code is a somewhat generic search utility that is written for a website generator.

Currently the search recurses through a given base directory searching for a string and returns the last instance of any directory with that name, or the first instance of any non-directory it finds.

Ex:

```
public static File findFile(File baseDir, String name) throws IOException{

    File match = null;
    for (File f : findFiles(baseDir, name)){
        if (match == null || 
                match.isDirectory() || 
                matchesFile(name, f) > matchesFile(name, match)){
            match = f;
        }
    }
    return match;
}

public static Set<File> findFiles(File baseDir, String name) throws IOException{

    Set<File> files = new HashSet<File>();

    for (File f : baseDir.listFiles()){

        if (!f.isDirectory()){
            if (matchesFile(name, f) > 0){
                files.add(f);
            }
        }else{              
            files.addAll(findFiles(f, name));

            if (matchesFile(name, f) > 0){
                files.add(f);
            }
        }
    }

    if (matchesFile(name, baseDir) > 0){
        files.add(baseDir);
    }

    return files;
}
```

As this is a fairly large build taking up to an hour and my machine is rather slow I would like to optimize this a bit. I think I know what I am doing but I don't actually know if this will be faster or not. 
I am thinking of changing the code like so:

```
public static File findFile(File baseDir, String name) throws IOException{

    File match = null;
    if(!baseDirHash.containsKey(baseDir.getAbsolutePath())){
        baseDirHash.put(baseDir.getAbsolutePath(), baseDir);
        hashBaseDir(baseDir, baseDir);
    }

    match = baseDirHash.get(baseDir.getAbsoluteFile() + name);

    if(match == null || !match.exists()){
        for (File f : findFiles(baseDir, name)){
            if (match == null || 
                    match.isDirectory() || 
                    matchesFile(name, f) > matchesFile(name, match)){
                match = f;
            }
        }
    }

    if(!match.isDirectory()){
        baseDirHash.put(baseDir.getAbsoluteFile() + name, match);

    }

    return match;
}
...
private static void hashBaseDir(File baseDir, File currentDir) throws IOException{

    for (File f : currentDir.listFiles()){

        if (!f.isDirectory()){

            baseDirHash.put(baseDir.getAbsolutePath() + f.getName(), f);

        }else{

            hashBaseDir(baseDir, f);

        }
    }
}
```

Any support or information on making my code more optimal or problems I didn't think of would be great.

Comment: Have you tried using the `FileVisitor` interface in Java? You don't have to reinvent the wheel for this purpose. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/walk.html

Comment: Have you tried the [`find`](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?find) utility?  It's been thoroughly tweaked.  `find . -type d -name foo` should yield all directories named `foo`.

Comment: @MikeSamuel-But,why would he need `find` utility of unix/linux over here in java.. I don't think there exists any connection. Are you suggesting him to refer to the code of `find` command?

Comment: @shekharsuman, No.  I'm saying it's easier to solve his particular problem using tested and optimized utilities instead of writing, optimizing, and debugging a Java program.

Comment: @MikeSamuel-Actually he already mentioned that he is doing all this as a part of a project! Did I read wrong? Probably NO! Anyways,don't feel it,it was just a poking...

Comment: @Mohammad I hadn't looked thanks. I don't know if it will solve all of my problems because I think that some of the code is relying on the current existing constraints.

Comment: @MikeSamuel Would it work in a windows environment? Also I need the behavior to be consistent with the current existing code so that I don't cause additional problems.

Comment: The `find` command exists on Windows, either with Git Bash either with Gnu Win32 Utils. I do use it, and spawning new processes can be slow. So, if you need to read the content of those file (aka do something like this: `find ... | while read file; do java ... ; done` or `find -print0 | xargs -r0 java` which find the file, then invoke java with each file or all files (xargs)), you should really do it in Java as running the JVM outweight the performance gain of find (and probably that the `find` version on Windows lags behind the `find` on Linux).

Comment: This comment apart, what does `matchesFiles` do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up just implementing it and it is about 400% faster.

Edit: 
A few optimizations that improve the over all code.

Note: This code is not thread safe as I am using static methods and variables.